# How can I delete a post from a supergroup in telegram with telegram-cli?

Tags: telegram

we have a group in telegram and we have a rule says no one must leave a message in group between 23 to 7 am , I wanna delete messages  comes to group between these times automatically . could anyone tell me how I can do that with telegram cli or any other telegram client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new version of [telegram-cli](https://valtman.name/telegram-cli). It's not fully open source, but you can download a binary from its site. Also you can find some examples there.

I hope the following snippet in JavaScript will help you to achieve your goal.

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var readline = require('readline');

// delay between restarts of the client in case of failure
const RESTARTING_DELAY = 1000;

// the main object for a process of telegram-cli
var tg;

function launchTelegram() {
  tg = spawn('./telegram-cli', ['--json', '-DCR'],
             { stdio: ['ipc', 'pipe', process.stderr] });
  readline.createInterface({ input: tg.stdout }).on('line', function(data) {
    try {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.name == 'SyntaxError') {
        // sometimes client sends not only json, plain text process is not
        // necessary, just output for easy debugging
        console.log(data.toString());
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
    if (obj) {
      processUpdate(obj);
    }
  });
  tg.on('close', function(code) {
    // sometimes telegram-cli fails due to bugs, then try to restart it
    // skipping problematic messages
    setTimeout(function(tg) {
      tg.kill(); // the program terminates by sending double SIGINT
      tg.kill();
      tg.on('close', launchTelegram); // start again for updates
                                      // as soon as it is finished
    }, RESTARTING_DELAY, spawn('./telegram-cli', { stdio: 'inherit' }));
  });
}

function processUpdate(upd) {
  var currentHour = Date.now().getHours();
  if (23 <= currentHour && currentHour < 7 &&
      upd.ID='UpdateNewMessage' && upd.message_.can_be_deleted_) {
    // if the message meets certain criteria, send a command to telegram-cli to
    // delete it
    tg.send({
      'ID': 'DeleteMessages',
      'chat_id_': upd.message_.chat_id_,
      'message_ids_': [ upd.message_.id_ ]
    });
  }
}

launchTelegram(); // just launch these gizmos
```

We activate JSON mode passing `--json` key. **telegram-cli** appends underscore to all fields in objects. See all available methods in [full schema](https://core.telegram.org/schema).