# how to delete a chat message which posted in telegram-cli?

Tags: telegram

I need to delete a message that's posted in chat (private or group or super-group). Is there any command in `telegram-cli` or other telegram clients that 
do this? If not, what should  i do?

I only saw this command `delete_msg <msg-id>` in telegram-cli wiki page, but i don't know what's `<msg-id>`.

Comment: See [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056347). Note that for deleting messages you should have its ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.
When run `telegram-cli` from command line you must pass `-N` or `--enable-msg-id` argument. This will add a sequential number before every message. Now when you want to delete a message with `delete-msg` you need to pass the number that is before message.

```
Telegram-cli version 1.5.1, Copyright (C) 2013-2015 Vitaly Valtman

[Ready] 0> msg Ali Hello
[07:30]  262 Ali <<< Hello
[Ready] 0> msg Ali How r u dude?
[07:30]  263 Ali <<< How r u dude?
[Ready] 0> delete_msg 263
```